# Why doesn't fixed effects regression using lm function drop time-invariant variables?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, plm

Unit-fixed effects regression is supposed to drop time-invariant variables because time-invariant variables are absorbed by unit-fixed effects. This happens when we use `plm` function, but not with `lm` function. Why?

I generate the data as follows. This is essentially a small panel data of 3 individuals * 3 time-periods with independent variable X, dependent variable Y, time-invariant covariates Z, as well as unit-fixed effect id and time-fixed effect t.

```
X = rnorm(9,0,1)
Y = 2*X
df <- data.frame(
  X,
  Y,
  Z = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  t = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
)
```

I first use `plm` function to conduct a unit-fixed effect regression as follows.

```
plmfit <- plm(Y~X+Z, index = c("id", "t"), effect = "twoways", model = "within", data = df)
summary(plmfit)
```

The output is like this:

```
Twoways effects Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = Y ~ X + Z, data = df, effect = "twoways", 
    model = "within", index = c("id", "t"))

Balanced Panel: n = 3, T = 3, N = 9

Residuals:
          1           2           3           4           5           6 
 1.7753e-15 -1.9565e-16  6.5662e-17  1.2292e-17  1.0598e-16  4.8263e-17 
          7           8           9 
-3.4982e-18 -2.1355e-17 -2.9027e-18 

Coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error   t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
X 2.0000e+00 4.6806e-16 4.273e+15 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    19.528
Residual Sum of Squares: 3.2086e-30
R-Squared:      1
Adj. R-Squared: 1
F-statistic: 1.82585e+31 on 1 and 3 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

This is okay. The time-invariant Z is not reported.

Next, I use `lm` function to do the same thing.

```
lmfit <- lm(Y~X+Z+factor(id)+factor(t),data=df)
summary(lmfit)
```

The output is like this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X + Z + factor(id) + factor(t), data = df)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
 4.624e-16 -3.466e-16 -1.158e-16 -2.556e-16  1.228e-16  1.328e-16 -2.068e-16 
         8          9 
 2.238e-16 -1.701e-17 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.961e-16  3.257e-16  9.090e-01    0.430    
X            2.000e+00  1.918e-16  1.043e+16   <2e-16 ***
Z           -3.627e-16  3.475e-16 -1.044e+00    0.373    
factor(id)2 -9.204e-17  3.796e-16 -2.430e-01    0.824    
factor(id)3         NA         NA         NA       NA    
factor(t)2  -4.906e-16  3.531e-16 -1.390e+00    0.259    
factor(t)3  -3.636e-16  4.260e-16 -8.530e-01    0.456    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.237e-16 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 3.862e+31 on 5 and 3 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

As you can see, the time-invariant variable Z is not dropped. This is surprising. What is going on here? I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could give me an answer.

Comment: `lm` doesn't know the meaning of any of your variables. From a linear algebra perspective, `Z` is linearly dependent on the dummy variable created for `factor(id)3`. So `lm` can tell that it needs to drop either `Z` or `factor(id)3`. My guess is that it keeps the one that occurs earlier in the model formula. Your formula has `Z` before `factor(id)`, so `Z` is the one that is kept.

Comment: (Correction: I should say that `factor(id)3` is a linear combination of `Z` and `factor(id)2` and the intercept, `factor(id)3 = (Intercept) + -1 * Z + -1 * factor(id)2`. The general point of my above comment holds.)

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks for your comment! As I relocate Z after factor(id), Z has now become the one that is dropped. Thanks a lot!